# Вопрос по операторам JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Разбираюсь с чужим JavaScript кодом. Не могу понять, что значит фраза:

```
this.currency = function(){return this.foo() == "rur" && "р." || "$"};
```

Для меня как сишарпера это неправильное выражение, но что-то мне подсказывает, что оно означает следующее: если верно выражение `this.foo() == "rur"`, то вернуть `"р."` иначе `"$"`.
Верно ли мое предположение и где почитать о подобном?

Comment: первый раз такое вижу, на тернарный оператор не похоже, скорее всего ошибка, вместо && надо ?, а вместо || надо :, поэтому предположение вряд ли верное

Comment: За предположения спасибо, про тернарный оператор знаю, но в данном коде все работает как описано. Вот и ищу причину. Может, один из используемых фреймворков такое поведение вносит. Понять бы...

Comment: Сколь мастеров набежало )) Не слушайте никого, правильно говорите, возвращается не bool, а первое вычисленное выражение, а оно может быть равно и "asd".

Если бы "p." с чем-то сравнивалось, тогда бы bool уже был

UPD: поэтому можно делать так:

    function func(param) {
        param = param || "default_value";
    }

Comment: Работать оно, может, и работает, но работает ли так как надо :) Как написал ниже @artem328, выражение в данном виде всегда возвращает true, но по виду оно очень похоже на попытку тернарного оператора.

Comment: @MasterAlex, вы название метода посмотрите и посмотрите, что он возвращает, все верно здесь - он возвращает валюту, что и должен.

Comment: @bopoh, а есть где-нибудь описание такого поведения. Оно используется по всему проекту и хотелось бы понять, как работает.

Comment: @BOPOH, хм, теперь проверил и правда работает, теперь только вопрос, зачем так? :)

Comment: @MasterAlex, ну я стандарты JS не писал )) Может быть, потому что нельзя передать значения в функции по дефолту? Может быть, были другие причины, я не знаю, но такое поведение задокументировано, поэтому можно считать, что по какой-то причине такое поведение оправдано.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно думаете, читайте [доки](http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators):

> Однако, в javascript операторы && и || возвращают не булево значение, а один из операндов, определивший значение выражения. Конечно, результат в таком случае может быть и не булевым.

Т.е. `return true && 'asd'` вернет 'asd' именно потому, что от него зависит, чему будет равно выражение. Поэтому в функциях можно использовать следующее:

```
function func(param) {
    param = param || 'default_value';
    return param;
}
var result = func();
console.log(result); // default_value
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем так, почитайте: http://javascript.ru/boolean-operators
Ну и корректной записью будет через тернарный оператор в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0):

**Upd.** мой мозг взорвался. Этот [код работает](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/y7c8kfbk/). Ну да, [вот же](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators). Не знал.

---

То, что вы имели в виду пишется так: `условие ? если_верно : если ложно`. [Про порядок/приоритет операторов](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). Сначала `==`, потом `&&` и потом `||`:

```
this.currency = function(){
    return
    (
        (    
            (
                this.foo() == "rur"
            )
            && "р."
        )
        || "$"
    )
};
```

- `==` — равенство без проверки типа;
- `&&` — логическое И;
- `||` — логическое ИЛИ.

Answer (score 0):

По идее, это выражение всегда возвращает истину. 
Не пустая строка при переводе в булевый тип возвращает true，т.е. "р." == true и т.п.

В вашем примере возвращается

```
this.foo() == "rur" // true/false
and (&&)
"р." // true

or (||)
"$" // true
```

А как известно, при условии "или" достаточно одного true, чтоб вернуть его.

А ваши догадки записываются следующим образом:

```
return this.foo() == "rur" ? "р." : "$";
```

Называется это тернарное выражение.